# Boto3 response for last modified date of File in GMT

Tags: python, datetime, amazon-s3, boto3

I am running some boto3 s3 calls. Getting the files along with their last modified date. 
I need the date format as GMT/ But getting it in the format as per my machine.

Below is the reference to my response -

```
{u'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 5, 3, 10, tzinfo=tzlocal()), u'ETag': '"xxxxxx"', u'StorageClass': 'xxxxx', u'Key': u'xxxx', u'Size': xxx}
```

Since I will have these files in 100, I don`t want to change each modified date to GMT. Is there any way I can get the response directly in GMT. My Application only supports GMT time.

Comment: Can you share your complete code? You should be getting the time in UTC

Comment: In python datetime object, as long as you format the output without timezone adjustment, the date time should be GMT+0. Please check out python datetime object formatting. (most file/object storage date time is stored in Epoch format, timezone adjustment is external)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to get the format using strftime

```
time=datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 5, 3, 10, tzinfo=tzlocal())    
time.strftime('%a, %m %b %Y %X GMT')
```